# How can I solve an overflow error in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I have to analyze a very large file of data and get some of the data and put it into another sheet, it works until I have around 20,000 rows but after that it gives me an overflow error and I need it to analyze around 200,000 rows, is it possible?

```
Sub prueba()

Dim i As Double, j As Double, k As Double, l As Double
Dim i2 As Double
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Double


lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 1
While Sheet1.Cells(18, i) <> "Suma de Máximo"

    i = i + 1

Wend

j = 1
While Sheet1.Cells(18, j) <> "Suma de Stock"

    j = j + 1

Wend

k = 1
While Sheet1.Cells(18, k) <> "Sum of Mínimo"

    k = k + 1

Wend

If Sheet1.Cells(18, k) = "Sum of Mínimo" And Sheet1.Cells(18, j) = "Suma de Stock" Then

    For i2 = 18 To LastRow - 1

        If Sheet1.Cells(i2, k) <> Sheet1.Cells(i2, j) Then

            Sheet2.Cells(i2 - 17, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i2, 1)
            Sheet2.Cells(i2 - 17, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(i2, 2)
            Sheet2.Cells(i2 - 17, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(i2, i)
            Sheet2.Cells(i2 - 17, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(i2, k)
            Sheet2.Cells(i2 - 17, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(i2, j)

        End If

    Next i2

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: try to change lrow as long

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Dim lrow As Integer
> ```

That's a 16-bit signed integer type, with a maximum value of 32,767 (2^15-1): it will overflow as soon as you assign it to 32,768 or higher. Any worksheet has many times more rows than that, and that makes `Integer` an inappropriate data type to use for storing worksheet row numbers.

Use a `Long` instead, it's a 32-bit signed integer type with a maximum value of 2^31-1, which is more than the number of rows Excel worksheets have.

`Double` is a floating-point data type that doesn't make much sense to use for row numbers. Consider using meaningful names instead of single-letter variables, but do note that these loops are wildly inefficient:

> ```
> k = 1
> While Sheet1.Cells(18, k) <> "Sum of Mínimo"
>
>     k = k + 1
>
> Wend
> ```

Use `Range.Find` when you need to quickly locate a cell with specific contents.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Dim i As Double, j As Double, k As Double, l As Double
Dim i2 As Double
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Double
```

with:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
Dim i2 As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
```